# How to build Spark with different version of json4s-jackson?

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, pom.xml, spark-streaming

I use Spark 1.4.1, Maven and IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4.

After finding this question [Is it possible to use json4s 3.2.11 with Spark 1.3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216712/is-it-possible-to-use-json4s-3-2-11-with-spark-1-3-0) I realise that in order to use `json4s-jackson_2.10:3.2.11` functionality within my Spark streaming application, I need to rebuild Spark with the updated json4s version in the pom file.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `core/pom.xml` so it references 3.2.11 ([not 3.2.10 as it's now](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/pom.xml#L201-L205)) and build Spark as described in [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

As to how it changes your applications, you should add the dependencies for Spark and json4s using appropriate versions as `provided` (since they come with Spark and are *provided* at runtime by Spark).