# Spark json4s[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/Js]

Tags: apache-spark, json4s

Team,

I am getting the error while using spark 2.4.0 on AWS EMR. Getting below error while parsing the Json string on spark version 2.4.0 and scala 2.11.8

```
Spark json4s[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/Js]
```

However Parse method is working with spark 2.3..x version. Could you please assist me o how to approach the maven dependency issue.

Comment: see my response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57663146/228843

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark streaming + json4s-jackson dependency problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400061/spark-streaming-json4s-jackson-dependency-problems)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with emr 4.3.0 and spark 1.6
solved it with installing json4s in the bootstrap action by :

1. down load the json4s jar and put it in s3
2. create the following shell script and put it in s3

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
    wget -S -T 10 -t 5 https://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucketname/json4s-native_2.10-3.2.4.jar
    mkdir -p /home/hadoop/lib
    mv json4s-native_2.10-3.2.4.jar /home/hadoop/lib/
   ```
3. add it as a bootstrap step in the emr launch steps

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464362/9147332