# is JSON4S compatible with spark 2.4.0 and EMR 5.26.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, json4s

```
Spark json4s[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/Js]
```

Getting above error while parsing complex json when running spark scala structured streaming application on aws emr.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a binary compatibility error... Could you please check the dependency tree for incompatible versions of `json4s` artifacts?

If you will not able to upgrade them to use the same version then possible you can solve the problem by shading some of them with sbt-assembly plugin using rules like [these](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/c3abc3908fb9dd9f160b9edcc2ef3859883850f9/jsoniter-scala-examples/build.sbt#L12-L14).

In any case I would recommend to use more safe and efficient parser like [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) (or [dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) that is based on it).

Comment: Thank you. I have used play-json and spary-json instead of json4s.